# Comparing and highlighting time values

Tags: excel, vba

I am parsing and analyzing large data sets and attempting to highlight rows that share the same time of occurrence.  This is a smaller piece of a larger macro and is currently the only piece not working (the rest works rather well!)  I am trying to compare each time to the time before it and after it in order to capture all occurrences.  If I compare just the time before, or just the time after, you can probably see how that would miss a lot of values. Code:

```
'Hightlights trade structures via time

Do
DoEvents

row_number = row_number + 1

'row_color_tester is a proxy for testing trade time "structure principle"
row_color_tester = row_number
tradeTime = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & row_number)

If tradeTime = Range("B" & (row_color_tester + 1)) Or tradeTime = Range("B" & (row_color_tester - 1)) Then
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 8

End If
Loop Until row_number = lastRow + 1
```

Sample data:

```
16:01:30
15:37:56
15:08:38
15:08:38
14:40:56
14:29:36
14:28:10
14:28:10
14:23:48
14:21:49
14:21:49
14:21:49
14:21:49
14:21:49
14:21:49
14:20:01
14:20:01
14:20:01
14:20:01
14:20:01
14:20:01
14:19:52
14:19:52
14:19:52
14:19:52
14:19:52
14:19:52
14:19:43
14:18:57
14:18:43
14:18:34
14:17:50
14:17:50
14:17:46
14:17:46
14:17:13
14:16:50
14:16:50
14:16:50
14:16:50
14:16:50
14:16:50
14:14:59
14:14:59
14:14:59
14:14:59
14:14:59
14:14:59
14:12:38
14:11:27
14:10:11
14:10:11
14:07:17
13:56:46
13:55:16
13:55:16
13:55:16
13:51:59
13:51:59
13:51:59
13:51:59
13:51:59
13:51:59
13:51:39
13:51:39
13:51:39
13:51:39
13:51:39
13:51:39
13:50:45
13:50:45
13:50:45
13:50:45
13:50:45
13:50:45
13:46:49
13:46:49
13:45:12
13:45:12
13:44:31
13:44:31
13:44:31
13:44:31
13:44:31
13:44:31
13:43:32
13:43:32
13:43:32
13:43:32
13:43:32
13:43:32
13:41:58
13:35:46
13:35:46
13:35:46
13:35:46
13:35:46
13:35:46
13:35:25
13:35:25
13:35:19
13:35:19
13:35:07
13:35:07
13:35:07
13:35:07
13:35:07
13:35:07
13:27:57
13:27:57
13:20:40
13:20:40
```

Comment: if the conditional formatting provided in the answers does not work then you need to explain a little better, than "not working".  The conditional formatting does exactly what the code above is trying to do.  So what is not working? Does it throw and error? Does it not do what you want? your need to be more specific.

Comment: I explained what was wrong with it in my response to the conditional formatting post below.  It does not work because A) it is missing values that it should be highlighting B) I am unable to rotate the colors it highlights in.

Comment: I wish it worked because it's the simplest solution to the problem by far.

Comment: That's the thing, you have no where in your description on the original post that you want the colors to "Rotate".  Edit your OP to describe the exact outcome desired and what specifically is not working in your code.  Or you will get answers that do not address what you want, and once an answer is given, that people on the site feels answers the question they stop looking.  In short, we can not read your mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to why it is not working, times are tricky, they essentially are a formatted number.  For example (0.598483796296296 to 0.598483796296300) will format to 14:21:49.  This is why the way you have will sometimes work and sometimes not.

to fix it add `.text` to the end of the three ranges:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("B" & row_number).Text
```

This way you are only comparing the formatted text.

Also it is good practice not to use activecell. Use:

```
Rows(row_number).entirerow. Interior.colorindex = 8
```

Comment: Thanks Scott.  So what appears to be happening now is the code is finding the similar time stamps, but it is highlighting the row that is 4 lows below and then getting stuck and no longer highlighting any further.  My thought is it has something to do with the current active row or active cell?

Comment: @user1041958. See edit   I am on my phone it may have typos but hopefully you will get the just.

Comment: We are thinking along the same chain!  I just tried this when your notification popped up.  I still had an error, but your solution fixed it.  Thank you very much for your time and effort!  Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have had to do something like this multiple times in the past. I always use the code found here:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/findall.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the times start in row 2 and column 1, a simple solution,  can be attained with the following conditional formatting:

[image]

for the following range:
[image]

Comment: This solution does not work as it misses a lot of values and I am unable to change the color for each structure.  By structure I mean each grouping of time signatures.

Comment: Sorry that the solution does not appear to work.  As I'm looking at your code more closely, I notice that the times are in column B, which would require that the formula be `=AND(OR(B2=B1,B2=B3),NOT(LEN(B2)=0))` and the range be `$B:$B`.  When I tested it on my side I had no missing values, however I will try to provide a solution that incorporates your existing code.  2 Questions though - 1) Are you saying that your code is missing certain values, and if so which ones? AND 2) How would you like the grouping format to change? (for example iterate ColorIndex by 1 each time)

Comment: it is missing values that it should capture.  They appear to be random some are in the middle of a sequence of similar times and some are at the end or beginning.  Iterating the colorind by 1 each time would work fine.

Comment: Demetri it appears to be working well now actually.  Thank you very  much I will utilize this solution.  Thanks for your help.